# Kindle Reader Addon SDK

Tags: kindle

Does anyone know if there is an addon SDK for the Kindle Reader?  I don't want to develop a full-blown app, just some additional functionality for the reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's called the [Kindle Development Kit (KDK)](http://kdk.amazon.com/gp/vendor/kindlepubs/kdk/gateway?ie=UTF8), but it's in limited beta. You have to apply for a license to use it for development.

Answer (score 0):

heres the link: [Kindle Development Kit](http://kdk.amazon.com/gp/vendor/kindlepubs/kdk/gateway?ie=UTF8)

you need to submit a request to become a beta developer to use it at the moment though. :(